# adjust base view size ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am trying to create an app with a friend picker, similar to that in Facebook, and other similar apps ([using ECSlidingViewConroller](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController)).  I have the slider working so far, however because it is sliding to the left, revealing a view below it, on the right, some text is being covered up.

I'm not sure what the best way to handle this situation is, but my gut feeling was to try to resize the entire view, so that I wouldn't have to resize other things, like if I wanted to add a nav controller, etc.

[image]

You can see some names on the left that are being covered. I tried resizing the views frame like this

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

also the window

```
[self.view.window setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

Neither of which changed anything.  What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.slidingViewController.underRightWidthLayout = ECFixedRevealWidth
```